# Why does my program just halt, with no exception thrown?

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code. An error occurs and the code simply breaks at `_clientStreamWriter.Flush();` at the `SendData` method.

No error is given, no exception is thrown... the program just stops. Any help? Thanks!

```
public class clsTCPClient
{
   TcpClient TCPClient = new TcpClient();
   StreamWriter _clientStreamWriter;

   public bool Connect(string Dest, int Port)
   {
       try
       {
           if (!TCPClient.Connected)
           {
               TCPClient.Connect(Dest, Port);
               _clientStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(TCPClient.GetStream());
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           utilities.WriteLog(utilities.LogDir + "\\AEOS.log", e.ToString());
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   public void SendData(string Data)
   {      
       try
       {
           //send message to server
           _clientStreamWriter.WriteLine(Data);
           _clientStreamWriter.Flush();

       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           utilities.WriteLog(utilities.LogDir + "\\AEOS.log", e.ToString());
       }
   }    
}
```

Comment: If no error is given, how do you know an error occurs? What does the main logic look like? You've got a class here, but no usage of it explained. =)

Comment: Where are you trying to send the data to? Is this your code too, or some external program listening on that address and port?

Comment: By defult the time out is 0.... that's why it was just hanging there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a reliable connection. You need to read all data on the server side and properly finish reading for your code to move further. You probably will get the exception after timeout.

**Edit:**

I just tested it and actually Flush() shouldn't block even if you don't accept socket or read any data on server side. So it must be some other problem.

Comment: this is a little misleading; network IO usually has a few buffers etc; it shouldn't need to actually be **consumed** by the server. Yes, TCP is *reliable*, but that is usually handled at the hardware / driver / OS layer, not at the application layer.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem... I had to add a TCPClient.SendTimeout = xxxxx to set the timeout and the error was thrown.